# NoReverseMatch, but resolved on page refresh

Tags: python, django, django-registration

Using Django 1.8.6 and Python 2.7.9, I am encountering a strange phenomenon where my account activation URL is throwing a "NoReverseMatch" error, but once if I refresh the page, the error is resolved and the account is successfully activated. I've tried removing the '$' from each URL, I've tried namespacing URL's, and I've tried replacing the redirect with a template view. None of those have solved the error.

More specifically, I get the following error: `Reverse for 'registration_activation_complete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`.

**registration.backends.default.urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

from .views import ActivationView
from .views import RegistrationView


urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^activate/complete/$',RedirectView.as_view(url='https://www.gather.kitchen/login/')),
                       url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
                           ActivationView.as_view(),
                           name='registration_activate'),
                       url(r'^register/complete/$',
                           TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/registration_complete.html'),
                           name='registration_complete'),
                       url(r'^register/closed/$',
                           TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/registration_closed.html'),
                           name='registration_disallowed'),
                       )

if getattr(settings, 'INCLUDE_REGISTER_URL', True):
    urlpatterns += patterns('', 
        url(r'^register/$',
            RegistrationView.as_view(),
            name='registration_register'),
    )

if getattr(settings, 'INCLUDE_AUTH_URLS', True):
    urlpatterns += patterns('', 
        (r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),
    )
```

**registration.backends.default.views.py (ActivationView)**

```
class ActivationView(BaseActivationView):
    def activate(self, request, activation_key):
        """
        Given an an activation key, look up and activate the user
        account corresponding to that key (if possible).

        After successful activation, the signal
        ``registration.signals.user_activated`` will be sent, with the
        newly activated ``User`` as the keyword argument ``user`` and
        the class of this backend as the sender.

        """
        activated_user = (RegistrationProfile.objects
                          .activate_user(activation_key))
        if activated_user:
            signals.user_activated.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                        user=activated_user,
                                        request=request)
        return activated_user

    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        return ('registration_activation_complete', (), {})
```

**registration.views.py (ActivationView)**

```
class ActivationView(TemplateView):
    """
    Base class for user activation views.

    """
    http_method_names = ['get']
    template_name = 'registration/activate.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        activated_user = self.activate(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if activated_user:
            success_url = self.get_success_url(request, activated_user)
            try:
                to, args, kwargs = success_url
                return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
            except ValueError:
                return redirect(success_url)
        return super(ActivationView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def activate(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Implement account-activation logic here.

        """
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

The debugger indicates that the error is occurring in the method 'get' at the line `return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)`.

Also, the local vars I am passing are the following:

```
self: <registration.backends.default.views.ActivationView object at 0x0394A570>
args: ()
request: "<WSGIRequest\npath:/accounts/activate/686420ac51ee99765c2847b819513365d6e812fc/........etc.>"
activated_user: <MyUser: abc123@example.com>
to: 'registration_activation_complete'
success_url: ('registration_activation_complete', (), {})
kwargs: {}
```

There are other similar SO questions out there, and I have already tried implementing all of the solutions that have been proposed. None of them have been fruitful. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: I don't see a pattern named 'registration_activation_complete' in your urls.py